# Runtime error 1004 Using Vlookup and Named ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried both sets of code below and either get runtime error 1004 or no answer if if put in error handling.

```
res.Cells(rlr, 8) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
                      res.Cells(rlr, 6), Repetition, 2, False)
```

And

```
res.Cells(rlr, 8).FormulaR1C1 = Evaluate("VLOOKUP(" & _
              rec.Cells(2, 16) & "," & Repetition & ",2,FALSE)")
```

Repetition is a dynamic named range, I have tried manually doing this and it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
res.Cells(rlr, 8).Value = res.Evaluate("VLOOKUP(" & _
          res.Cells(2, 16).Address & "," & Repetition.Address & ",2,FALSE)")
```

Assuming `rec.Cells(2,16)` was a typo and all ranges are on sheet `res`

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for this but for some reason I get no result from this either. If I remove my On error statement I get runtime error 424 object required. It seems like a lot of people have had issues with this previously.

Comment: So some variable is not set, either `res` or `Repetition` (or both) - is the second one an actual `Range` object, or the *name* of a Range ?